# Structured array in csharp?

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following C++ code that i want to translate to C#

But i'm stuck in the definition of "Element" which is a structured array.

What is best to use ?

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

for (i = 0; i< 8; i++)
{
    Ixx += Element[i].vLocalInertia.x + Element[i].fMass * (Element[i].vCGCoords.y*Element[i].vCGCoords.y + Element[i].vCGCoords.z*Element[i].vCGCoords.z);
    Iyy += Element[i].vLocalInertia.y + Element[i].fMass * (Element[i].vCGCoords.z*Element[i].vCGCoords.z + Element[i].vCGCoords.x*Element[i].vCGCoords.x);
    Izz += Element[i].vLocalInertia.z + Element[i].fMass * (Element[i].vCGCoords.x*Element[i].vCGCoords.x + Element[i].vCGCoords.y*Element[i].vCGCoords.y);
    Ixy += Element[i].fMass * (Element[i].vCGCoords.x * Element[i].vCGCoords.y);
    Ixz += Element[i].fMass * (Element[i].vCGCoords.x * Element[i].vCGCoords.z);
    Iyz += Element[i].fMass * (Element[i].vCGCoords.y * Element[i].vCGCoords.z);
}
```

And have the following type struct :

```
typedef struct _RigidBody {

float       fMass;          // total mass (constant)
Matrix3x3   mInertia;       // mass moment of inertia in body coordinates (constant)
Matrix3x3   mInertiaInverse;// inverse of mass moment of inertia matrix (constant)

Vector      vPosition;      // position in earth coordinates
Vector      vVelocity;      // velocity in earth coordinates
Vector      vVelocityBody;  // velocity in body coordinates
Vector      vAngularVelocity;// angular velocity in body coordinates
Vector      vEulerAngles;   // Euler angles in body coordinates
float       fSpeed;         // speed (magnitude of the velocity)

Quaternion  qOrientation;   // orientation in earth coordinates
//Matrix3x3 mRotation;      // rotation matrix

Vector      vForces;        // total force on body
Vector      vMoments;       // total moment (torque) on body

Matrix3x3   mIeInverse;     // inverse of moment of inertia in earth coordinates


} RigidBody, *pRigidBody;

typedef struct _BodyElement {
    float   fMass;
    Vector  vDCoords;
    Vector  vCGCoords;
    Vector  vLocalInertia;
    float   fIncidence;
    float   fDihedral;
    Vector  vNormal;
    float   fArea;
    int     iFlap;
} BodyElement, *pBodyElement;
```

Comment: What do you understand by “structured array”? It seems that `Element` is simply an array/vector of some class. You can do the exact same thing in C#.

Comment: What is `Element`? How is it declared? What does `list` have to do with it? Are you sure the code you show is C++ and not C# (C++ doesn't have the keyword `var` and `List` and `KeyValuePair` seems like .net classes)?

Comment: I'm sorry, quite a newbie here. I'm trying to use this code http://pastebin.com/gRGzvzx5 inside a GameEngine (Unity)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
 public struct Element
    {
        public struct coord
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
            public int z;
        }

        public coord vLocalIntetia;
        public int fMass;
        public coord vCGCoords;

    }

    Element[] element = new Element[8];
```

**EDIT**

Or this (with your added detail)

```
 public struct BodyElement 
    {
        float   fMass;
        Vector  vDCoords;
        Vector  vCGCoords;
        Vector  vLocalInertia;
        float   fIncidence;
        float   fDihedral;
        Vector  vNormal;
        float   fArea;
        int     iFlap;
    }


    BodyElement[] element = new BodyElement[8];
```